# itk x and y component of the gradient of an image

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gradient, itk

I would like to calculate the x and y component of the gradient of a 2D image. As in MATLAB is calculated with ***[dT2,dT1] = gradient(T);***

```
ReaderType::Pointer T_g     // image 
FilterType::Pointer gradientFilter = FilterType::New();
gradientFilter->SetInput( T_g->GetOutput());
gradientFilter->Update();
```

With this sentence, I get the result, but I want to have the x-component and the y-component
gradientFilter->GetOutput()
Is there any method to extract it? I am looking for it but I have no positive result!

Thanks so much

Antonio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of the gradientFilter will be a vector image. I assume from your description it's
a 2d image!

```
ImageType::IndexType index;
index[0]=xcoord;
index[1]=ycoord;

gradientFilter->GetOutput()->GetPixel(index)[0]; // will return first component of xcoord,ycoord
```

Comment: the last '[0]' is not working , also if I try index[2]= 0 is algo giving me an error!

Comment: index[2] should give you an error if you're working with a 2d image! try "std::cout << gradientFilter->GetOutput()->GetPixel(index) << std::endl" and see what the output is

Answer (score 1):

http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples

http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/ImageProcessing/NthElementImageAdaptor

template
class itk::NthElementImageAdaptor< TImage, TOutputPixelType >

Presents an image as being composed of the N-th element of its pixels.

It assumes that the pixels are of container type and have in their API an operator[]( unsigned int ) defined.

Additional casting is performed according to the input and output image types following C++ default casting rules.

Wiki Examples:

```
All Examples

Extract a component of an itkImage with pixels with multiple components

Process the nth component/element of a vector image
```